# Leaflet popup with dynamic content not centered over marker

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am trying to create a leaflet popup with dynamic content, it works but the popup bubble is not aligned with the marker.

Here is a screenshot, its clear that the popup bubble is not centered over the marker.
[image]

Here is the code

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
}).addTo(map);


m = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
m.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup<span id='a'></span>", {maxWidth: "none"})
m.openPopup();

$('#a').html('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Also here is a minimal jsfiddle example that describes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nk93shkt/

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like leaflet is determining the width of the infobox when it renders it. You're adding text after it's been displayed so leaflet no longer knows its actual size, and thus cannot center it properly.

Try the `setPopupContent()` method from the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setpopupcontent) in this slightly long-winded example:

```
m = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
m.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup<span></span>", {maxWidth: "none"})
m.openPopup();
var a = m.getPopup();
var b = a._content.replace("<span></span>","<span>asdasdasda</span>");
m.setPopupContent(b);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nk93shkt/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this is an issue for anyone **without** dynamic content; the issue of an offset popup for any customised icons can be explored in [this documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/)

see:

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
```

From the example and edit the `popupAnchor:` value to fit your specific zoning requirements

Answer (score 0):

The position gets set initially, so you could manually adjust it with jQuery

```
m.openPopup();
adjustPopup('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>sdfsdfs<br>sdfsdfsdf');
function adjustPopup(html)
{
    $('#a').html(html);
    var $leaflet=$('#a').closest('div.leaflet-popup');
    var width=$leaflet.width();
    $leaflet.css({left:"-"+(width/2)+"px"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was added to Leaflet's API after the original answer was chosen, but you should be able to use method update() after changing the content of the popup.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-update